# Laravel redirecting authenticated users to login route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

When I try to access any route under the auth middleware I get redirected to a login route.

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('area-cliente/resumo', 'AreaClienteController@resumo')->name('area_cliente_resumo');

});
```

this is my authenticate middleware

```
 class Authenticate extends Middleware
 {
/**
 * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return string
 */



protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if(Auth::guard('cliente')->guest())
    {
        return route('registrar');
    }


        return next($request);

   }
 }
```

I cannot see where the code that is redirecting to a login route is located and I don't know why either, since the user is apparently logged using the code below;

```
 public function logar(Request $request) {

    $credenciais = [

        "email" => $request->email,
        "senha" => $request->senha
    ];

 $results =  auth()->guard('cliente')->login(Cliente::find(1));

 if(auth()->guard('cliente')->check()){

     //I am able to echo the name of the user
     //echo auth()->guard('cliente')->user()->name
     return redirect()->route('home');
 }
 else{
     echo "no";
 }

}
```

I've also tried to clean (remove all functions) of the RedirectIfAuthenticated and authenticate middleware but the behavior of the application doesn't change, I still being redirected to a login page on the routes under the auth middleware.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are getting to your middleware? Put a `dd('here');` In the first line of your redirectTo function.

Comment: Yes, "here" is displayed on the page and if leave the redirectTo function empty it still redirects to a login route.

Comment: I solved the problem by  making a change to the config/auth.php. I changed the default  guard from web to cliente. Now the application is performing the expected behavior that I wanted.

Comment: You should post your answer so that in future someone get the reference code. Keep coding 